# Flutter Pdf Viewer performance

Tags: performance, flutter, pdf

I'm creating an educational application for poor students who have android devices running on `Android 4.1` and above.

I tried lots of packages but
most of them make the app crash and the rest take long to load the file and the application becomes heavy to use.

Is there a package or a way to improve the the performance?

I don't want to convert the pdf pages to images because this will make the size of the app very big to download.

These are the packages that I used:

```
flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.6
pdf_image_renderer: ^0.5.0
advance_pdf_viewer: ^1.2.2
flutter_cached_pdfview: ^0.3.5 #min API Level 20
printing: ^5.2.1
pdf_flutter: ^1.1.4
flutter_pdf_viewer: ^0.6.1
native_pdf_view: ^4.0.1
flutter_pdfview: ^1.1.0
```

`

Comment: "I tried lots of packages" <- What kind of packages? "most of them make the app crash" <- What did you write? What kind of crash? With did you do with the "packages" to get the crash? What was thwe specific cause of the crash? What is "the file"? I really don't understand your question.

Comment: I wrote all the packages I tried in the end,  most of them just copy the examples provided by the package and change it to my pdf file, The app crash every time I try to open it on android 4.1 and it works fine on android 6.0 .

Comment: Is there a another package that reads pdf files and support android 4.1 or a way to improve the the performance?

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing issues with every pdf viewer then my suggestion would be to not use your app pdf viewer instead if possible you can use the default pdf viewer which generally comes preinstalled in devices. And you would need a way to know if a phone has an app that can open pdf files or not and in case it is not there then use your app pdf viewer.

The second option would be to split the pdf files into multiple pdf files like chapters, etc. I think this option is very much viable.

Also, you can try this package [syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer). I'm using it as of now and it is good.